# How does Android's BluetoothManager work with multiple devices?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have some questions about using BluetoothManager in an Android app that needs to manage multiple devices.

Does the expression "context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager" always return the same instance of BluetoothManager? Does the "adapter" property always return the same BluetoothAdapter? If the answer is "yes", are the objects thread-safe?

Can I connect to and manage multiple Bluetooth devices simultaneously, assuming I pass a unique BluetoothGattCallback object to the connectGatt function for each device?

Can I have multiple scans running simultaneously, assuming I use a unique ScanCallback object with each scan? Will the scans behave independently (can they have different filters and settings) or will they all receive the same results?

Can I connect to a device while scanning is still active or do I need to cancel the scan before I connect? How would this work if I'm doing more than one scan in parallel?

Thanks,
Frank